# Using Kendo UI for JQuery in Angular2 ASP.Net Core app

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I'm trying to build an Angular2 app on a ASP.Net Core Web API.

I have the basic plumbing in place...using Angular http to call the web api returns data.

For the presentation, I want to use Kendo UI.  I see that the KendoUI for Angular2 is still in Beta, and the Grid requires an oData Service (as opposed to a Web API Service).

So I'm thinking to use the 'plain' old KendoUI for JQuery components in my Angular2 components and UI templates.  However, I'm not sure how to go about this.

Do I just add kendo ui references to my packages.json file?  What do I then "import" in my component to be able to use these?

Comment: I used these two projects as examples: https://github.com/gsaadeh/angular2-kendoui, https://github.com/haoguanjun/angular2-kendoui

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kendo UI widgets for jQuery along with Kendo UI components for Angular in the same application. It is recommended to apply this approach only for components that have no counterpart in the Angular suite.

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/framework/kendo-jquery/